# SK_RMEM_ALLOC Defintion

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, exploit, netlink

I am doing research on CVE-2017-16939 and trying to understand the exploit code for an assignment; however, I cannot find clear information on what sk_rmem_alloc represents.

**Can someone point me in the direction of documentation that answers these questions?:**

- **What does sk_rmem_alloc represent in reference to Netlink sockets?**
- **How does it interact with sk_rcvbuf and
  netlink_skb_set_owner_r?**

Link to exploit code: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/44049

Link to vulnerability: https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-16939/

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) It is okay to point you in the right direction but in this case it seems as if you're asking for us to answer the question entirely.

Comment: I'm not asking to solve it entirely. I am trying to figure out the code overall and cannot figure out that one small piece of the code. Which appears to be completely within guidelines. @Monstarules

Comment: If someone could point me in the direction of documentation, that would be helpful.